# Need help for simple python loop

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

I am trying to compute the probability of rolling a dice n number of times and finding the average.Its basically a Monte Carlo problem. I am new to coding so if someone can help I would really appreciate it.

```
import random 
import sys

num = int(sys.argv[1])
roll =random.randint(1,6)
sum=0
for roll in range(0,num):
    sum = sum + int(input())
    average = sum / num
    print('the average is: ',average)
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do on the error line? Are you trying to get input from the user, and if so what are you trying to use it for?

Comment: "asap" ? Is this a homework problem with a deadline? In general "asap" gets a negative reaction on Stack Overflow. You are asking for help, don't demand it on your time schedule. Also, "I am having issues with my code" is vague. What are the issues that you are having?

Comment: @JohnColeman I am sorry for my language, I was just trying to get attention. I am trying to learn python on my own and I am stuck in this particular code for a while. I am also new to the forum. Excuse me again sir. I seriously didn't mean to offend anyone or be mean

Comment: @M-Chen-3 I am trying to add up the random rolled number. I am not trying to get an input. I think I did a mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a bunch of issues here.

- You should only use the `input()` function when you want to prompt the user for input. Here that is not the case.
- You want the print statement outside of the loop, not inside the loop.
- [A minor stylistic point] You should not name a variable "`sum`", since that is a built-in function name, and it's not good form. You can do it, but if afterwards you want to use the actual `sum()` function, you'll run into problems.

I think this is what you intended:

```
import random
import sys

num_rolls = int(sys.argv[1])
rolls = [random.randint(1, 6) for i in range(num_rolls)]
print('the average is: {}'.format(sum(rolls) / num_rolls))
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your feedback and answer, that's exactly what I was looking for, may I ask you why you used "format(sum(rolls) / num_rolls) "

Comment: Using string formatting gives you more flexibility (number of decimals shown, spaces vs. tabs, ...), and tends to be better programming style.

Comment: @emiravc `sum(rolls)` adds up all the items in rolls. Then `sum(rolls) / num_rolls` divides the sum by the number of objects, calculating the average. Then the `format()` function basically plugs the result into the curly braces (due to how formatted strings work).

Comment: Oh I see thanks a lot that helps me so much! Please excuse me for my language asking the question. I am new to the stack overflow. I was just trying to get attention, I actually didn't think people would help me.